# How would I make Else work in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm playing around with Batch a little bit and I've encountered a problem that I think you guys could help with. So I'm trying to make a thing where you can answer Yes or No on a question, and if you don't answer Yes nor No then it'll tell you that it wasn't a valid answer. You can take a look at the code right here.

```
:Choice
set /p Choice=Is a stone a stone?
if %Choice%==Yes goto Correct
if %Choice%==No goto Incorrect
else goto Invalid

:Correct
echo You are correct!
pause
goto end

:Incorrect
echo You are incorrect!
pause
goto end

:Invalid
echo You did not enter a valid answer.
pause
goto end

:end
exit
```

So I cannot use Else in the way I've done in the code, but do you know how I would do the same thing as Else would do IF it worked? May sound a little confusing, I hope you understand. Just to clarify, here's the bit I don't know how to do:

```
else goto Invalid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave out the word else, and have an unconditional Goto after your two `if` statements.

```
set /p Choice=Is a stone a stone?
if %Choice%==Yes goto Correct
if %Choice%==No goto Incorrect
goto Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcting answer: You can find information about using ELSE in batch below. However, David's answer is more elegant:

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/else.html

Comment: You can guess that site's page for `else` based on the URL for `if`: http://ss64.com/nt/else.html.

Comment: You will find the keyword ELSE in the cmd help by typing `IF /?` so please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is correct.  I only add this answer (using your code) to show you that ELSE does exist and how you might use it.  Note that I use quotes on strings in case there are spaces or special characters in variable... or in case the variable is blank.  I also used /i to specify a case insensitive compare.  Note that the ) else ( has to be on the same line.  It could have been on the same line as the line above it; or all 3 of those lines could be on 1 line.

```
:Choice
set /p Choice=Is a stone a stone?
if /i "%Choice%"=="Yes" goto Correct
if /i "%Choice%"=="No" (goto Incorrect
   ) else (
   goto Invalid)

:Correct
echo You are correct!
goto end

:Incorrect
echo You are incorrect!
goto end

:Invalid
echo You did not enter a valid answer.
pause
goto :Choice

:end
pause
exit
```